# preventing the trigger of Task T2 when task T1 which calls stored procedure when an error is returned

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need help with a practical scenario. I had stored procedure where it copies data from an external location into intermediate table, and returns the error message when there is no file in the external location. this is called using task T1.

after loading the data into intermediate table T1 has to trigger another task (T2) to transform the data and finally load it into the target table. when there is no file in the external location, how to prevent the task T2 from triggering.
after that it has to send an email alert about non availability of a file. any guidance is helpful.

Comment: If you are properly failing your T1 task, Snowflake will not execute T2.  The email alert is trickier, though.  You'd likely need a separate task that continually executes, looks for errors in the task history, and sends notifications based on the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use of snowflake [**STREAMS**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html) feature can help you here.

You can create a **STREAM** based on your intermediate table.

```
create stream my_stream on table my_intermediate_table;
```

Then you can condition execution of your task T2 on the presence of unconsumed data from your stream using **WHEN** parameter

```
WHEN
   SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('my_stream')
```

Your task T2 is used to transform and load date in a final table. Instead of querying data from your intermediate table make it consume the stream content with a **DML** statement.

```
INSERT INTO my_final_table SELECT * FROM my_stream;
```

When new data is inserted into your intermediate table, this will allow your task T2 to be triggered as your stream contains data. If your stream is empty then your task T2 execution will be skipped as your **WHEN** will not be fulfilled.

Snowflake will not allow you to natively send emails alerts for tasks monitoring.
You will have to scan metadatas using [**TASK_HISTORY**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/task_history.html) to find tasks executions status and external features like ETL tools or Snowflake external functions to send emails.